# Converting & modifying a list of NamedTuples into a List of Dict's

Tags: python

I need to convert a list of Named Tuples:

```
[Fruit(name='banana', colour='yellow', delicious=True), Fruit(name='mangosteen', colour='purple', delicious=True)]
```

Into a modified list of Dict's (note the extra `text` key):

```
[{'name': {'text': 'banana'}, 'colour': {'text': 'yellow'}}, {'name': {'text': 'mangosteen'}, 'colour': {'text': 'purple'}}]
```

I have managed to find a solution that works, but it seems ugly, I am fairly new to Python.

```
Fruit = namedtuple('Fruit', 'name colour')
fruitlist=[]
fruitlist.append(Fruit('banana', 'yellow'))
fruitlist.append(Fruit('mangosteen', 'purple'))

newfruitlist = []
for fruit in fruitlist:
    fruitdict = dict(fruit._asdict()) #convert NamedTuple to Dict
    tempdict={}
    for key, value in fruitdict.items():
        tempdict[key]={ 'text': value }
    newfruitlist.append(tempdict)
```

Question: what is a better/cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine list and dict comprehensions:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Fruit = namedtuple('Fruit', 'name colour')
fruitlist=[]
fruitlist.append(Fruit('banana', 'yellow'))
fruitlist.append(Fruit('mangosteen', 'purple'))

out = [{k:{'text':v} for k, v in f._asdict().items()} for f in fruitlist]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'name': {'text': 'banana'}, 'colour': {'text': 'yellow'}}, {'name': {'text': 'mangosteen'}, 'colour': {'text': 'purple'}}]
```